# Dojo build issues if require is used conditionally to load another module in one layer which requires modules already included in the first layer

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo-build

I have a scenario where I am trying to build dojo and my app into one single file by adding everything to one single layer.
However, in dojo's gfx/render the renderer is determined dynamically and a require statement is used to get the module for that renderer.
Thus after build I donot have these render modules in my final js file.

When I load the final js file it tries to find the renders in their actual location.

If I add those files as they are in a new Layer, then it leads to new issues. The loaded renderer module defines other dojo modules in its dependency list and most of them already have been included in the previous final js file (Layer 1).

Thus this leads to large layers.

What solution can be used to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include dynamically required modules as well in your build... To do so, you can create a loader module (e.g. LoaderModule) and require those dependencies in it and then add that module as a dependency to one of the modules in your layer. Shortly:

LoaderModule.js:

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',

    /* Add all dynamically required modules here to include in production build */
    'dojox/gfx/renderer'

], function(declare) {
    return declare(null, {});
});
```

And then add LoaderModule as a dependency to one of your core modules.